# Calculate Levenshtein Distance across all entry pairs in dataframe without repeating pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this dataframe:

```
  Animal       Name Months
0    dog      Rosie     45
1    cat     Archie     12
2  snake  Archibald     14
```

Now, I would like to calculate the Levenshtein distance of the *Name* column entries amongst all pairs of *Name* data entries. I would like my resulting table to look like this:

```
         id1        id2  LevScore
0      Rosie      Rosie         0
1      Rosie     Archie         4
2      Rosie  Archibald         8
4     Archie     Archie         0
5     Archie  Archibald         4
8  Archibald  Archibald         0
```

However, right now I'm only able to take a cross product of all data entries using this code:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df1['Name'], df1['Name']), columns=["id1","id2"])
new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
```

...and there are multiple duplicate data entries (e.g. Rosie-Archie and Archie-Rosie), and end up with a table like this:

```
         id1        id2  LevScore
0      Rosie      Rosie         0
1      Rosie     Archie         4
2      Rosie  Archibald         8
3     Archie      Rosie         4
4     Archie     Archie         0
5     Archie  Archibald         4
6  Archibald      Rosie         8
7  Archibald     Archie         4
8  Archibald  Archibald         0
```

Any help is appreciated to remove the 'duplicate' (Rosie-Archie = Archie-Rosie) entries :)

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to generate the last table?

Comment: Just edited the post!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `combinations_with_replacement` from `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

from textdistance import levenshtein

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["Rosie", "Archie", "Archibald"],
})

new_df = pd.DataFrame(combinations_with_replacement(df1['Name'], 2), columns=["id1","id2"])

new_df["LevScore"] = new_df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)

new_df
#          id1        id2  LevScore
# 0      Rosie      Rosie         0
# 1      Rosie     Archie         4
# 2      Rosie  Archibald         8
# 3     Archie     Archie         0
# 4     Archie  Archibald         4
# 5  Archibald  Archibald         0
```

Comment: Additionally, I would like to ask 3 more things. a) Would it be possible to have ids instead of the actual animal names in new_df? (e.g. Rosie:0, Archie:1, Archibald:2) b) How to write to multiple columns. Imagine if levenshtein returns 2 numbers, how could I write these 2 numbers to 2 different columns? c) How can I have only certain entries make it into the final new_df, e.g. those whos levenshtein distances are smaller than 5. Rather than post-filtering, I would like to have it done concurrently, so as to avoid very large dataframes with large amounts of data. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @You_Donut,  I did not understand your questions. I recommend asking them separately, with reproducible examples.